# Cross-platform way to execute command with clean environment?

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell, unix, environment-variables

A plugin I use executes:

```
silent execute '%!cmd'
```

which fails because of a particular environment variable I have set that deliberately modifies the behaviour of `cmd`.

*I* can fix it with:

```
silent execute '%!ENV_VAR= cmd'
```

But I can't contribute that upstream because it won't work on Windows. I believe the Windows equivalent would be:

```
silent execute '%!set ENV_VAR= && cmd'
```

though I can't readily test it.

Is there a platform agnostic way of doing this, say invoking `execute` with a fresh environment?

Comment: Just `let $ENV_VAR=newvalue | %!cmd | let $ENV_VAR=oldvalue`?

Comment: :facepalm: Thanks! (Will accept answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As any child process inherits the environment from its parent, you can temporarily redefine Vim's own environment before executing your tool:

```
let [temp, $ENV_VAR] = [$ENV_VAR, '']
%!cmd
let $ENV_VAR = temp
```

Comment: Setting a variable to an empty string is not *exactly* the same as unsetting it... Which is actually possible with `unlet $ENV_VAR`. A more complete solution would actually check that the environment variable is actually set before unsetting it.

Comment: @filbranden For _environment variables_ that's precisely the same thing.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27708/281844

Comment: @filbranden And so what? The link says that _some_ applications can make a difference. But Vim does not.